# How to translate using a transformation matrix?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am using imguizmo lib to transform objects in a scene in my project that i am working on using directx 11. imguizmo takes in a model matrix to transform the gizmo. it works fine, but in order to snap the gizmo to a vertex i would need to give it a transformation matrix that translates it to that vertex, and this is how i make that 4x4 translation matrix

```
[ 1.f, 0.f, 0.f,  x  ]
[ 0.f, 1.f, 0.f,  y  ]
[ 0.f, 0.f, 1.f,  z  ]
[ 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f ]
```

xyz are the coords to where i want to translate the gizmo.

However it doesn't work. After this my gizmo disappears. isn't that how translation matrices work???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you are using row-major matrices, row vectors, and pre-multiplication (Direct3D style) or  column-major matrices, column vectors, and post-multiplication (OpenGL style).

The translation above appears at first glance to be 'OpenGL style'.

For Direct3D, I usually expect it to be written like:

```
[ 1.f, 0.f, 0.f,  0  ]
[ 0.f, 1.f, 0.f,  0  ]
[ 0.f, 0.f, 1.f,  0  ]
[ x,   y,   z,    1.f ]
```

Generally one is a transpose of the other.

It also depends on if you are using column-major or row-major matrices for your HLSL shaders, which may require the matrix be transposed as you put it into the constant buffer.

See [this blog post](http://seanmiddleditch.com/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/).

> If you are new to DirectX programming, you should consider the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) helper wrapper for [DirectXMath](https://walbourn.github.io/introducing-directxmath/) that is included in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: What's a Direct3D style matrix like??